# Page locking in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-4.0

Here is an overview of my ASP.NET Page setup. Framework is 4.0.

There is a Page with tabs with a user control in each tab of it. There's a lock button on the Page which locks and unlocks the page. The page will be auto locked when any user opens it. This is the current setup. But now we need the following scenario:

The Page should not be locked on user opening it. But when he tries to edit or change any info in the fields of the Page it should lock the Page. I guess this is more of a client side Issue. So, when another user tries to open the Page and edits it, it will be locked for him too as it is a separate client. So, there should be a mechanism in ASP.NET to notify the server that a page is locked when user tries to edit the info on the Page so when other users try to modify the page, they get a 'locking' error.

So my question is how do I achieve the above and what are the things to consider?

I know in ASP.NET we can write code for user events like clicking a button etc.. but not sure of techniques for achieving the above. Any input would be a great help.

Comment: Can you elaborate on `page locking`? Do you mean all buttons and inputs are disabled?

Comment: Nope..while other users can open the page but cannot lock it..only the lock button is disabled for them. while the user who has the lock can edit it still.

Comment: Basically you have a page that you want to only be editable for one person at a time, even if multiple people are viewing the page, is that right?

Comment: That should happen only if the user starts editing any of the fields on the page,if he is just viewing it should not be locked. current system takes it as  editing even if the user has opened just for viewing....down vote for that?

Comment: Use a database that stores an identifier for that page. On `Page_Load` doe a check to see if that identifier has a record in the database. If it does, disable the button.

Answer (score 1):

You could store something in the [application cache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hbbsfk6%28v=vs.140%29.aspx) with an expiry period set to however long you want the page 'locked' for. Each time there is a postback you would check for this value in the cache and either 'lock' the page or return an error to the user. Each time the page is loaded when not postback you would disable the button and/or input controls.

Something like this in `Page_Load` should be a reasonable starting point:

```
string usernameWhoHasLock = (string)Cache["PageIsLockedByUser"];
if (usernameWhoHasLock  == null)
{
  // Page is not locked, lock it:
  usernameWhoHasLock = HttpContext.Current.Identity.Name;
  Cache.Insert("PageIsLockedByUser", isLocked, null, EXPIRYDETAILS);
}
else
{
   // Page is locked. If IsPostback, allow edits if is the user with the lock, otherwise return an error. If not postback, disable the edit button unless is the user with the lock.
}
```

For the arguments to supply to `Cache.Insert` decide what expiry policy you need and refer to the documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc491414(v=vs.110).aspx). IsPostback documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

you may consider implementing pessimistic locking in database where record will be explicitly locked and stay locked unless it's released (in this case saved/cancelled). not very easy to implement properly though.